# how to set custom ref-variable in gmock

Tags: googlemock

I am using gmock in my project and I meet a problem to set a custom reference variable for a mock function.
Suppose I have a class as following:

```cpp
class XXXClient {
public:
    void QueryXXX(const Request&, Response&);
}; 

class XXXRunner {
public:
    void DoSomething(XXXClient&);
};
```

There is a Client Class XXXRunner::DoSomething using XXXClient::QueryXXX, and I Want to mock XXXClient to test XXXRunner::DoSomething.

The problem occurs that the second parameter of QueryXXX , that is 'Response', is not a return value, but a reference variable, which I fill some data into Response in  XXXClient::QueryXXX. I want to set a custom data for the Response to verify different condition of XXXRunner::DoSomething.

The gmock framework can set expected returned value, but I cannot not find a way to set the "returned variable" ?

So How to do so?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, make a `XXXClient` mock class, let's name it `XXXClientMock` as following:

```cpp
class XXXClientMock : public XXXClient
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(QueryXXX, QueryResult (Request&, Response&));
};
```

Then, use GMock Action `SetArgReferee` to set the custom parameter, as following:

```cpp
TEST(XXXRunnerTC, SetArgRefereeDemo)
{
    XXXCLientMock oMock;

    // set the custom response object
    Response oRsp;
    oRsp.attr1 = “…”;
    oRsp.attr2 = “any thing you like”;

    // associate the oRsp with mock object QueryXXX function
    EXPECT_CALL(oMock,  QueryXXX(_, _)).
        WillOnce(SetArgReferee<1>(oRsp));
    // OK all done

    // call QueryXXX
    XXXRunner oRunner;
    QueryResult oRst = oRunner.DoSomething(oMock);
    …

    // use assertions to verity your expectation
    EXPECT_EQ(“abcdefg”, oRst.attr1);
    ……
}
```

**Summary**
GMock provide a series of actions to make it convenient to mock functions, such as `SetArgReferee` for reference or value, `SetArgPointee` for pointer, `Return` for return, `Invoke` for invoke custom mock function (with simple test logic), you can see [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md) for more details.

Enjoy it :)
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `SetArgReferee` in the Google Mock [cheat sheet](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Actions).