# Specifying output string argument with GoogleMock

Tags: c, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm evaluating the Google Test/Mock as a framework for unit tests of my C code.

How can I specify the output string argument for the function I would like to mock?

Here I have `int get_int_param(const char *)` is the function to test and it uses `int _get_text_file_content(const char *fn, char *content)` function that I want to mock.

How to specify this `char *content` that is going to be the result of execution of mocking function?

I'm struggling with this code:

```
TEST(GetParameterTest,Positiv){
   const static int strLen=29;
   char *text=(char *)calloc(strLen,1);
   strcpy(text, "param1=1\nparam2=42\nparam3=3");

   MokedFunctions mokedFunctions;
   EXPECT_CALL(mokedFunctions, _get_text_file_content("process.conf",_)).Times(AtLeast(1)).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<1>(text));

   EXPECT_EQ(1, get_int_param("param1"));
}
```

and got this compile error:

```
/usr/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h: In instantiation of ‘typename 
testing::internal::Function<F>::Result testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, 
value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::gmock_PerformImpl(const args_type&, 
arg0_type, arg1_type, arg2_type, arg3_type, arg4_type, arg5_type, 
arg6_type, arg7_type, arg8_type, arg9_type) const [with arg0_type = 
const char*; arg1_type = char*; arg2_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; arg3_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; arg4_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; arg5_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; arg6_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; arg7_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; arg8_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; arg9_type = 
testing::internal::ExcessiveArg; F = int(const char*, char*); int k = 1; 
value_type = char*; typename testing::internal::Function<F>::Result = 
int; testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, 
value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::args_type = std::tuple<const char*, char*>]’:

 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h:664:23:   required from 
 ‘static Result testing::internal::ActionHelper<Result, 
 Impl>::Perform(Impl*, const std::tuple<_U1, _U2>&) [with A0 = const 
 char*; A1 = char*; Result = int; Impl = 
 testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<1, char*>::gmock_Impl<int(const char*, 
 char*)>]’

 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:168:1:   required from 
 ‘testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, 
 value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::return_type 
 testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, 
 value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::Perform(const args_type&) [with F = 
 int(const char*, char*); int k = 1; value_type = char*; 
 testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, 
 value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::return_type = int; 
 testing::SetArgRefereeActionP<k, value_type>::gmock_Impl<F>::args_type 
 = std::tuple<const char*, char*>]’

 test_param.cpp:68:1:   required from here
 /usr/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:175:3: error: size of array is negative
 GTEST_COMPILE_ASSERT_(internal::is_reference<argk_type>::value,
 ^
 In file included from /usr/include/gmock/gmock.h:65:0,
             from test_param.cpp:2:
  /usr/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h:177:28: error: assignment of read-only location ‘std::get<1u, {const char*, char*}>((* & args))’
    ::std::tr1::get<k>(args) = value;
                        ^
  make[1]: *** [test_param.o] Error 1
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12):

`SetArgReferee` expects the argument to be a C++ reference, which it's not it your case.

In general, in order to better understand these actions it helps to think of them as operations over the argument `arg`:

- `SetArgPointee(value)` is essentially `*arg = value` (`arg` must be a pointer)
- `SetArgReferee(value)` is `arg = value` (`arg` must be a reference)
- `SetArrayArgument(first, last)` is `memcpy(arg, first, last - first)` (`arg` must be a pointer)
- `SaveArg(ptr)` is `*ptr = arg`
- `SaveArgPointee(ptr)` is `*ptr = *arg` (`arg` must be a pointer)

Given that, it becomes obvious that the action you need is `SetArrayArgument<1>(text, text + strlen(text) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a C++ testing framework for C code.  Unless you're willing to compile your code with g++ (instead of gcc), it's not going to work.  Gcc can't compile C++ code.

Comment: Yes sure, I'm compiling my C code with gcc and then compile my tests and link them with g++. No problem, it is working quite good.

Comment: Ok, so are you doing something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552805/using-google-mock-for-c-code

Comment: yep, my solution is a bit dirty but it is based on this post

Comment: In line  EXPECT_CALL(mokedFunctions, _get_text_file_content("process.conf", _ )).Times(AtLeast(1)).WillOnce(SetArgReferee<1>(text));
 you have an underscore as an argument.  I'm not an expert at google mock so I could be missing something but that doesn't look right.

Comment: `::testing::_` is a wildcard from GMock. It means that there is any value of correct type is expected. My understanding of this is: "I'm expecting everything that is correct pointer as an input" and then I want to specify the output at this pointer, that in turn is predefined (`SetArgReferee`).

Comment: Hey, just a bit of a shot in the dark but it looks like SetArgReferee only accepts reference or value.  I think you're supposed to use SetArgPointee for pointers.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845753/how-to-set-custom-ref-variable-in-gmock

Comment: It looks now like it tries to dereference the pointer. `gmock-actions.h:695:31: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Try just using a string there and pass in a reference to SetArgReferee