# GoogleMock: How to SetArgReferee according to another input parameter?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I would like to use GoogleMock to mock a service as below:

```
class Request
{
    int req_id;
    int request;
};

class Response
{
    int req_id;
    int response;
};

int request(Response& res, const Request& req)
{
    res.req_id = req.req_id;
    res.response = 2 * req.request;

    return 1;
}

EXPECT_CALL(mock_service, request(_,_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(/* what here? */), Return(1)));
```

How can I `SetArgReferee` for the `Response& res` according to the passed in `const Request& req`, i.e. `res.req_id = req.req_id;` and `res.response = 2 * req.request;` ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8987602/1129815) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not look like something that could be mocked - but I guess this is just illustration of the problem.

So assuming that you have mocked function `reqest` within mocked class MockService - then use [`Invoke Action`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#using-a-function-or-a-functor-as-an-action) with your `request` function as parameter:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_service, request(_,_)).WillOnce(Invoke(&request));
```

If you like to just call  base class function - then do something like this:

```
class mock_service_class : public service_class
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(request, int(Response& res, const Request& req));
    int baseRequest(Response& res, const Request& req)
    {
        return service_class::request(res, req);
    }
};
```

And do your `EXPECT_CALL` in this way:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_service, request(_,_))
    .WillOnce(Invoke(&mock_servide, 
                     &mock_service_class::baseRequest));
```