# Can google mock mock the behavior of changing the out param?

Tags: unit-testing, googlemock

I start using gmock for my code recently, some of which rely on some other outside services or interfaces, so gmock is kind of perfect for me.

Say I have a trivial class A to mock

```
class A
{
    void foo(int& bar) {
        // will change bar
        bar = GetingResultFromSomeOutsideService();
    }
};
```

Now I create a mock class

```
class MockA: public A
{
    MOCK_METHOD1(foo, void(int& bar));
};
```

In my test case, I try to mock the behavior of `A::foo` of changing `bar` with `ON_CALL`, but I don't know how exactly.

For example, I want my `MockA::foo` always set `bar` to 1, so that my other codes invoking `A::foo` will always get `bar == 1` like this:

```
// some other piece of codes invoking A::foo
int bar = 0;
A my_a;
my_a.foo(bar);
cout << bar;   // always output "1" with gmock
```

Any hint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set custom ref-variable in gmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845753/how-to-set-custom-ref-variable-in-gmock)